# Insufficient Scope Permissions

Tags: json, web-applications, jsonp

I am developing a web application. In this application I will post a message on my stocktwits wall. Here I am getting an Error: Insufficient Scope Permissions. Anybody tell me what error it is...

My Code is

```
   <form name="chart" method="post" action="https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json?access_token=657c40d5a04615c973d474745f8f1311960dcc6d&'body=Message'">  
          <a id="post">Message Posting</a>  
          <input type="submit" value="Post" />  
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The token you're using doesn't have the permission for what you're calling for.

[Authentication docs](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication#scopes)

Comment: yes yes. I forget to put it. Thank you Dennis.. @Dennis Rongo